# How to convert world coordinate to view coordinate in VTK

Tags: vtk, coordinate-systems

In my program(python based), a point need to be converted from world coordinate([x,y,z]) to view coordinate([j,k,t],j and k are between -1 and 1,t is the depth) in VTK. I find the `vtkCoordinate` class with `SetCoordinateSystemToView()` method. But it does not work .

```
coordinate = vtk.vtkCoordinate()
coordinate.SetCoordinateSystemToWorld()  
coordinate.SetValue(x,y,z)
coordinate.SetCoordinateSystemToDisplay() 
viewCoord=coordinate.GetComputedValue(renderer)
```

The result is very odd and definitely wrong. There are some methods like `GetComputedDisplayValue()` or `GetComputedViewportValue()` that can get the corresponding result from a coordinate system to display or viewport coordinate system, but there is no method like `GetComputedViewValue()` . Very confused, need help,
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `world2ViewportMatrix=GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix(aspect,nearz,farz)` in class `vtkCamera` which can get the matrix that convert world coordinates to viewport coordinates.

Then `viewPortCoord=world2ViewportMatrix.MultiplyPoint([worldPosition[0],worldPosition[1],worldPosition[2],1])`

`[viewPortCoord[0]/viewPortCoord[3], viewPortCoord[1]/viewPortCoord[3]]` is the viewport coordinate( [-1,1]*[-1,1]),`[viewPortCoord[2]/viewPortCoord[3]` is the depth([nearZ,farZ])

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
import vtk

coordinate = vtk.vtkCoordinate()
coordinate.SetCoordinateSystemToWorld()
coordinate.SetValue(1,2,1)

# test:
from vedo import *
plt = Plotter()
print("press shift-I on the red dot, then press q")
plt.show(Cube(), Point([1,2,1], r=20), axes=1)

viewCoord = coordinate.GetComputedViewportValue(plt.renderer)
print(viewCoord) # matches!
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my program(vtk 9.0.3),  the results of `GetComputedViewportValue()`and `GetComputedDisplayValue()` are the same (pixel coordinate). what I want is normalized display coordinate( [0,1]) with depth information.